# lang.js:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, angular, facade, lang

[image]
**My package.json**

```
"ng2-file-upload": "1.0.3",
"ng2-translate": "2.5.0",
"angular2-cookie": "1.2.3",
"angular2-google-maps": "0.15.0",
"key-codes": "0.0.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12"
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0",
"@angular/router":  "3.0.0",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
"bootstrap": "3.3.6",
"es6-promise": "3.2.1",
"es6-shim": "0.35.1",
"ie-shim": "0.1.0",
"jquery": "2.2.4",
"moment": "^2.14.1",
"theuy-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^1.0.0"
```

Solution

You can fix this issue by using a babel-loader in your webpack.config.js

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-preset-es2015
```

after that you can add

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    // configuration
loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@angular\/common\/src\/facade\/.+))/,
            loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015'
        }
    ]
};
```

The thing is that the angular team did not export the facade as a es5 code but es6.

Comment: What does lang.js line 21 look like? What did you do right before this error happened? What have you done to try to fix the problem?

Comment: I've ran into the same problem, could you say what you did to fix it?

Comment: @domderen see the solution above

Comment: @TheuyLimpanont can you please help me how can i add the solution which you have provided above. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by using a babel-loader in your webpack.config.js

```
npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-preset-es2015
```

after that you can add

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    // configuration
loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@angular\/common\/src\/facade\/.+))/,
            loader: 'babel?presets[]=es2015'
        }
    ]
};
```

The thing is that the angular team did not export the facade as a es5 code but es6.